# error when receiving an array from the controller in a javascript function in project laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I get an error **"htmlspecialchars () expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"**. I am passing an array from the controller to the view and trying to collect it in a javascript function, Thank you very much for your help.

**Code controller**

```
$etis = EtiquetaPresupuesto::where('presupuestos_id', $id)->get();
$idEtiquetas=[];

foreach ($etis as $eti) {
    array_push($idEtiquetas, $eti->etiquetas_id);
}

return view('presupuestos_contabilidad/info-presupuestos', [
    'etiquetas_id' => $idEtiquetas,
]);
```

**Code javascript in view**

```
function etiquetas_sesion(){
    var array_etiquetas = {{$etiquetas_id}};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `json_encode()` function to get array or object.

> Also you can use `@json()` blade selector

For example:

```
function etiquetas_sesion(){
    var array_etiquetas = @json($etiquetas_id);
}
```

```
function etiquetas_sesion(){
    var array_etiquetas = {!! json_encode($etiquetas_id) !!}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$etiquetas_id` in your code is an array, but you're trying to print it as string via `{{ }}`, which escapes it through `htmlspecialchars()`.

If you want the array to be preserved in JavaScript (as JavaScript array), use `json_encode()`:

```
var array_etiquetas = {!! json_encode($etiquetas_id) !!};
```